# Generate frond end design from database values

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-5.0

I want to build a front end web page by taking the data or column names from backend SQL Server. It should take column name of table and should create fields like labels and text boxes or buttons. I am trying to search on Google for such tutorial or article but couldn't able to find it. If some body can help me with some sample code or tutorial on how to do that will be very much helpful.

Comment: If you are holding pure html in your database ( no asp.net ) then you could create a web method to get what you need from the database and access the created method with jQuery through ajax, and place all the returned content to an objects inner html.

Comment: @a.bajorinas can you please share link  or any sample code of you have. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you provide any more information? are you using web forms or mvc? Will the controls have events attached to them? What 'column names from backend SQL' supposed to mean? Do you want to build dynamic tables?